# How to click webelement that contains text i searched for using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm searching for some text using the foloowing code and trying to click on it, but for some reason i cant figure out no action takes place...why is that?

code:

```
for (int i=0; i<AllTableTd.size();i++){


    if (AllTableTd.get(i).getText().toLowerCase().contains("autesting".toLowerCase())) {

        AllTableTd.get(i).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
        break;

    }
```

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), \"" + document + "\")]"));

Comment: if i could use the xpath i wouldnt do this all loop, but the xpath is dynamic so i cant use it (not even with "contains"...)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use that web element do

WebElement we = driver.find element(your element);

we.click()

Or

driver.find element(your element).click();